# If the Wronskian $W(y_1,y_2)(0)=1$ then $W(y_1,y_2)(-1)=? $

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, wronskian

Given that $y_1,y_2$ be  a fundamental set of solutions of the ODE and $(\mathrm{e}^xy')'+y'+y=0, x>0$ if the Wronskian $W(y_1,y_2)(0)=1$ then $W(y_1,y_2)(-1)=? $

my attempt:

Given D.e can be written as $\mathrm{e}^xy''+(\mathrm{e}^x+1)y'+y=0$

hence by Abel's formula $W(y_1,y_2)(x)=c\,\mathrm{e}^{-\int \frac{\mathrm{e}^x+1}{\mathrm{e}^x}}dx=c\,\mathrm{e}^{-\frac{(\mathrm{e}^x+1)^2}{2}}$

Since $W(y_1,y_2)(0)=1 \implies c=\mathrm{e}^2$ , I getting doubt I am missing something can some one help please

Comment: $e^2$ is a constant. What's your doubt?

Comment: @AmanKushwaha. how to processed for further

Comment: Put $x=-1$ in the expression you got for $W(y_1,y_2)(x)$ after substituting the value of constant $c$ you got.

Comment: @AmanKushwaha..  i am not getting the correct answer? sir

Comment: Your question doesn't mention you are getting the wrong answer!

Comment: Your integration isn't correct

Comment: @AmanKushwaha.. where did I ?

Comment: @AmanKushwahai got thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$W(y_1,y_2)(x)=ce^{-\int \frac{e^x+1}{e^x} dx}=ce^{-\int 1+ \frac{1}{e^x} dx}=c e^{(e^{-x}-x)}$

$W(y_1,y_2)(0)=1 \implies c e^{(1-0)}=1 \implies c=\frac{1}{e}$

$\therefore W(y_1,y_2)(-1)=\frac{1}{e} e^{(e^{1}+1)}=e^{(e+1-1)}=e^e$